# How can I determine why my AWS Lambda function is quitting without an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a fairly complex `lambda function` that is quitting mid-operation with no apparent explanation.

It is no where near its time or memory limit and it suddenly just has an END and REPORT in the logs with no errors reported.

Note that it does not hang; it is a very short execution. Is there a way that something in Node can Segfault without it causing an error to be reported?

How do I dig deeper into this? I have audited the code many times over, and it exits very deep in the loop with a parallel async command running. I am not detecting an error being thrown from any of the callbacks. It simply stops.

Comment: Normally no segfaults, unless you're using such a crappy native extension.

Comment: Are you getting timeout?

Comment: Are you getting a timeout like this: https://serifandsemaphore.io/aws-lambda-going-beyond-5-minutes-34e381e71231?

Comment: If you hit the end of your code, execution will stop, even if you have synchronous tasks running, even if you don't signal it to end. See: [Everything Depends on Context or, The Fine Art of nodejs Coding in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/getting-nodejs-and-lambda-to-play-nicely/)

Comment: @abdulbarik - No, there are no timeouts. I am nowhere near my 5 minute limit.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Yes, I have 3 places where I call the main function callback (not context due to the new way you work with API Gateway), and all of them have a log statement before them and none of them are being called when going down the trouble path in the code.

Comment: Exceptions in NodeJS Lambda functions will not be logged automatically. You need to add try/catch blocks to capture and log exceptions. Otherwise if your code throws an exception it will appear in the logs as if your Lambda function simply exited abruptly.

Comment: @MarkB - Not sure about that? I have definitely had type errors and errors where I tried to call into non existing functions and gotten crashes in my logs. Are certain types of errors not logged?

Comment: I've had lots of errors disappear silently in NodeJS Lambda functions because I wasn't capturing them.

Comment: @MarkB - Ok, that is great to know. I'll give it a shot

Comment: @MarkB - Just had another thought... If this was my problem, i would get an error logged in the Lambda console error graph though, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a fairly deep investigation, I believe the issue is that AWS Lambda is terminating the execution because there are no remaining processes waiting. Keep in mind that by default, lambda does not stop execution just because you call the main callback or context and will keep executing. Unless a special flag in the context is set, it will continue to operate until timeout or until all the processes are finished. In my case, I tracked it down into an error in the node-apn package where a promise was not coming back after a push notification. Not sure of a resolution besides taking it out for now.

Answer (score 2):

I had this after missing an `await` before an `async function` call.

I spent far too long going down the rabbit hole of trying to work out why it was failing at the last point it logged - which was always the same every run (by chance, or rather the time it took).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see a time-out message in the logs, I mean in cloudwatch logs group of the lambda, and you have a successful invocation (2xx), which means that all treatments from lambda are completed.

Then you should probably check your **asynchronous code/Callbacks** inside your handler